# Shadows in a rounded rectangle in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, hybrid-mobile-app, shadow

I tried adding a shadow to a rounded container but Flutter adds shadows as if the container is a perpendicular rectangle, which I don't want. I looked up for this problem on Google but couldn't find any appropriate solution, please help me out.

**Code for Container**

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.28,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xFFF9D276),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, 4),
        color: Color(0xFFF9D276).withOpacity(0.15),
        spreadRadius: 4,
        blurRadius: 50
      )
    ]
  ),
)
```

**UPDATE**
Answer from @HardikKumar & How I actually want it

[image: Answer from @HardikKumar]

[image: REQUIRED]

Comment: What kind of shadow do you want? You want shadow to be only in one side?

Answer (score 2):

Problems in the code:

1. With the `blurRadius` of 50, you won't see any difference in shadow when you change the `spreadRadius` or the `offset`
2. With the `opacity` of 0.15, you will barely see any shadow (both in black or white backgound color)

Try this code:

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.28,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xFFF9D276),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        //offset: Offset(0, 4),
        color: Color(0xFFF9D276), //edited
        spreadRadius: 4,
        blurRadius: 10  //edited
      )
    
  ),
),
```

How it looks like:

[image]

If you need anything else, just let me know.

Comment: You're using `listView`? The image that you've posted doesn't have any shadow. Specify your problem correctly, what actually you need?

Comment: a slightly glowing shadow, which spreads only a little

Answer (score 1):

As far I get some idea from your first image, you can check the code below.

```
    Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Color(0xff000000),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              new BoxShadow(
                color: Color(0x73000000),
                blurRadius: 5.0,
                spreadRadius: 1,
                offset: new Offset(-10.0, 0.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.28,
//            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFF9D276),
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  new BoxShadow(
                    color: Color(0xff000000),
                    blurRadius: 0.0,
                    spreadRadius: -2,
                    offset: new Offset(2.0, 0.0),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I tested your code and the shadow shape appears with the same border as the decoration box

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juSDr.png)

I just edit the color of the shadow to black so i can see it better.

Maybe u want use a button like that , u need to use ButtonTheme to use height and width ,

**Final edition:**

Use Material , it has elevation property, shapeBorder and BorderRadiusGeometry, u can use an container as parent of Material for the width and height.

[Link to Material Widget on Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/Material.html)

Comment: Trying so hard to understand what u want , i think what u want is use the shadow of a container to create a blur effect arround the container.
he second photo that you provide, only shows as a difference to the first that the shadow is not even noticeable and that the color of the is somewhat lighter.
If what you want is a lifting effect, maybe you should use a flat button and use its elevation parameter, because I think you want to use the shadow to create that effect, so I recommend using a widget that allows "elevation"

Comment: do you know a widget as such?

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this code for rounded rectangle :)

```
Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.28,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green[700],
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(25)
          )
      ),
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8,top: 8),
       child: IconButton(
         icon: Icon(
            Icons.send,
            color: Colors.yellow[600],
            ),
         onPressed:() {}
        ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, top: 2),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.gray,
                          fixedSize: const Size(200, 50),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                          ),
                          side: const BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: ColorsConst.gray9),
                        ),
                        child: const Text("Text"),
                        onPressed: () => print('Text'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2, bottom: 2),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.gray,
                          fixedSize: const Size(200, 50),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                          ),
                          side: const BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: ColorsConst.gray9),
                        ),
                        child: const Text("Text"),
                        onPressed: () => print('Text'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ]
              )
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31979377)